# Redux Thunk handling network responses in a different order

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-thunk, fetch-api

I have a text entry field which (via a Thunk) queries the server of the validity of the user's text. As these requests can happen in very quick succession, they may be returned from the server in a different order than when they were sent. Therefor, the string in the text field may be shown as invalid, when in fact it is valid.

To fix this, I'm performing a check when I receive a response from the server - is the current content of the text field the same as what was checked? If not, check again. I feel there should be a better way to handle this situation than querying a DOM element value.

How can I follow through from pre to post server request?

```
export function updateUserCode(code) {
    return dispatch => {
        return dispatch(validateUserCode(code))
    }
}

function validateUserCode(code) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(updateCode(code))
        return fetch(`/api/code/${code}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => dispatch(receiveValidatedCode(code, json)))
            .catch(error => {Log.error(error)})
    }
}

function receiveValidatedCode(code, data) {
    const lastval = document.getElementById('usercode').value
    if (code != lastval) {
        // Code not the same as current value
        // need to validate again
        return updateUserCode(lastval)
    }
    if(data.success) {
        return {
            type: types.CODE_VALIDATED,
            code: code,
        }
    }
    return {
        type: types.CODE_INVALID,
        reason: data.reason,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Messing with DOM inside your logic is indeed less than ideal. I would suggest keeping last entered text field value in Redux store and perform your checks in reducer.

Also I don't see any point in re-validating user input if current entered value differs from one validated by last resolved request. Just ignore such responses and do not perform unnecessary request.

In terms of code you can do it like that:

```
// actions
const requestValidation = value => ({ type: 'request-validation', value });

const receiveValidation = (value, result) => ({ type: 'receive-validation', value, result });

export const validateUserCode = code => dispatch => {
  dispatch(requestValidation(code));
  return fetch(`/api/code/${code}`)
         .then(response => response.json())
         .then(json => dispatch(receiveValidation(code, json)))
         .catch(error => {Log.error(error)})
}

// reducer
export const validationReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'request-validation') 
    return ({ value: action.value, isValidating: true });

  if (action.type === 'receive-validation' && state.value === action.value) 
    return ({ value: action.value, isValid: !!action.success });

  return state; 
};
```

That is not production quality code, and I don't event sure if it works, but it reflects the idea.